# Hibernate restrict user from changing a value based on spring user roles

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a model class called Batch and it has an instance variable called intake. My requirement is to only allow users with admin role to change it's value.

My question is what is the best method to handle this situation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just do the logic where you update the Batch.intake variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a question, tagged with 'Spring', I suggest you use Spring Security for that. With Spring Security, you can secure methods via annotations. Eg.:

```
  @Component
  public class Batch {

     private int intake;

     @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     public void changeIntake( int intake ) {
        this.intake = intake;
     }
  }
```

Make sure also to enable global method security:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

You can read more about this topic on: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html